# Fuse won't push into slot

Tags: electrical, vw, jetta, fuse

Why won't my fuse push into its slot? Yes I'm using the correct fuse but it is very loose and won't snap in. This for my 12V plug in the trunk of my 2007 Jetta. Also, a put a new fuse in for the cigarette lighter 12 v, yes they are different amps I know, and it also is dead. Both 12v outlets dead is fishy! Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It sounds like you might be putting the replacement fuse in the wrong slot where there's no terminals to grab hold of the fuse

Comment: I know I'm a woman hence I must be stupid but uh NO! CORRECT SLOT, correct fuse.. 30 amp slot 35 .. anyone else wanna condescend or maybe HELP?

Comment: It is possible to bend the blades in the holder therefore making it impossible to subsequently insert the fuse...

Comment: Sometimes the spring clips which hold the contact blades of the fuse get loose so the fuse doesn't make good contact and/or falls out. To solve this, twist the both of the blades of the fuse the same direction by about 10-15 degrees, which will effectively make the fuse fatter, so the springs will hang on tightly. (This assuming that the fuse fully inserts into the slot, but doesn't "snap in" and remain in place.)

Comment: A photo of the fuses and slots would be helpful. And no, we are not judging you about your gender..

Comment: Add a photo of the fuse box and fuse.

Comment: @HandyHowie Martin already posted that...

Comment: @Jacquie, what has prompted you changing 2 fuses? Did they both go bad at the same time or were they separate issues? Also, were the fuses actually blown?

Comment: The 12v cigar lighter **and** the 12v trunk supply? Was it the same appliance that caused the fuse to blow when you tried it in different outlets? What wattage or amperage is the applicance? Is it *still* plugged in?

Comment: @Jacquie - Sorry if it seems we are asking stupid questions of you or saying something which would "only be stated because you're a woman" ... quite the contrary, we'd ask these types of things of ANYONE. The mods here want you to feel at home and free of gender bias. We don't believe the "Pink Tax" should be a real thing or anything else along those lines. We are all just here to help. If anyone here has offended you, please accept my apologies.

Comment: I'd also look closely into the slot to see if there is any burning or heat damage that is visible. It is possible (in theory) that sufficient heat could cause the terminals to melt and move into the holder plastic or for some fusing or flashing to have damaged the terminals themselves. *Possible* but I think other options are better...